Share secondary y-axis on facet plots created in loop
I want to create a facet-plot by looping over a provided number of rows and columns. All axes in this plot should share the same y-axis on the left for one value (ys) and a secondary y-axis on the right for the other value (zs).
I came up with a solution of which this is a very much stripped down minimal working example:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = x**2
y2 = 0.5 * x**2
y3 = 1.5 * x**2
y4 = 2 * x**2
ys = [y1, y2, y3, y4]

z1 = -10 * y1
z2 = -11 * y2
z3 = -10.5 * y3
z4 = -9 * y4
zs = [z1, z2, z3, z4]

cols = 2
rows = 2
k = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax2 = ax

for i in list(range(cols)):
    for j in list(range(rows)):
        ax[i,j].plot(x, ys[k], c='b')
        ax[i,j].tick_params(colors='b')

        ax2[i,j] = ax[i,j].twinx()
        ax2[i,j].plot(x, zs[k], c='r')
        ax2[i,j].tick_params(colors='r')

        k = k+1
plt.show()

This results in the following plot:

Here, the x-axis and first y-axis (blue) are nicely shared among the plots, but the second y-axis is not (red).
I imagined that by making ax2 = ax in the above code it would copy over the sharey=True parameter. Alas, it does not work like that.
How can I make the secondary y-axis behave like the primary y-axis? Meaning that ticks are present on all plots, tick labels (numbers) are only listed on the outermost plots and the y-axis is scaled similarly on all plots.
Please keep in mind that I want to maintain the iteration over columns and rows in the script as the actual plotted data has upwards of 60 panels.

I calculated min zs and max zs, and applied to y limits. I guess that calculate min and max should be easier with numpy than what I've done.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = x**2
y2 = 0.5 * x**2
y3 = 1.5 * x**2
y4 = 2 * x**2
ys = [y1, y2, y3, y4]

z1 = -10 * y1
z2 = -11 * y2
z3 = -10.5 * y3
z4 = -9 * y4
zs = [z1, z2, z3, z4]

cols = 2
rows = 2
k = 0

m = min(min(zs[i]) for i in range(cols * rows))
M = max(max(zs[i]) for i in range(cols * rows))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax2 = ax

for i in list(range(cols)):
    for j in list(range(rows)):
        ax[i,j].plot(x, ys[k], c='b')
        ax[i,j].tick_params(colors='b')

        ax2[i,j] = ax[i,j].twinx()
        ax2[i,j].plot(x, zs[k], c='r')
        ax2[i,j].tick_params(colors='r')
        if j != cols - 1:
            ax2[i,j].tick_params(axis='y', labelright=False)
        ax2[i,j].set_ylim(m, M)
        
        k = k+1

plt.show()



Thank you for this working solution! For the benefit of others: I have added:
if j == cols - 1: ax2[i,j].set_ylabel('Y label') in similar fashion to get an y-label on only the right outermost axes.
For the sharing of the secondary y-axis I found another solution was to add ax2[i,j].sharey(ax2[0,0]) in the loop just below ax2[i,j] = ax[i,j].twinx().
Regardless, I'm curious why a single min() and max() wouldn't suffice in your solution.
